# Correct way to compute the error variance of ordinary kriging

Tags: variance, covariance, kriging

I'm learning ordinary kriging and I found some discrepancies in the method of computing error variance among different materials I read, in general there are 2 different formula:

Method 1:

[image: Method 1 formula taken from Wackernagel 1995]

- [wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging)
- [Wackernagel H. (1995) Ordinary Kriging. In: Multivariate Geostatistics. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-03098-1_11)
- [Bailey & Gatrell Chpt 5](https://msu.edu/~ashton/classes/866/papers/gatrell_ordkrige.pdf)

Method 2:

[image: Method 2 formula taken from Bohling]

- [Bohling](http://www.people.ku.edu/~gbohling/cpe940/Kriging.pdf)
- [This geostatsmodels python repo that based on Bohling's material](https://github.com/cjohnson318/geostatsmodels).
- [Details of ordinary kriging](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/stat/chap34/sect15.htm), this one actually differs from the previous 2 by the sign of the `m` term, see the very last equation on that page.

So what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\mu_{0}$ is the Lagrangian parameter optimized in ordinary kriging, then both those equations are equal. The first form is always correct for any linear predictor (e.g. the equation works for both simple kriging and ordinary kriging).

Adopting the $w$ notation, the second form gets resolved when you consider the $\sum_{j} w_{j}=1$ constraint. In simple kriging, the solution obeys $\sum_j w_{j}C_{ij}=C_{i0}$. But in ordinary kriging, the system of equations is $\sum_j w_{j}C_{ij}+\mu_{0}=C_{i0}$. This allows for the substitution:

$\sum_{i} \sum_{j} w_{i}w_{j}C_{ij}=\sum_{i} w_{i}C_{i0}-\sum_{i} w_{i}\mu_{0}$

(The final term just adds to $\mu_{0}$.) Putting this into your first equation gives you the second. The equations between pg 111-112 in [these notes](https://msu.edu/~ashton/classes/866/papers/gatrell_ordkrige.pdf) make this very clear.